# Magento 2: How can I remove all products URL rewrites?

Tags: magento2, product, url-rewrite, sql

I've used a script to **TRUNCATE** all tables related to products, so removing all products in my store. Now I want to remove the more than 4k URL rewrites related to those products removed, though, maintaining the categories' URL rewrites.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To remove all URL rewrites related to the products, you can use that script SQL below.

```
DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type='product';
```

If you want just to remove the URL rewrites that were automatically generated, you can use this one.

```
DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type='product' AND is_autogenerated='1';
```

Comment: thanks for your help it helps me to resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from url_rewrite where 1=1;
ALTER TABLE url_rewrite AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

and then re-index