# How to delete all products in Magento 2 and start product id from 1?

Tags: magento2, database

I truncate all products tables but still product id not starting from 1. which query i'll run ? i want to start product id from 1. i'm working on localhost.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First run this query to delete all products

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity`;
```

then run below query to start product id from 1

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT =1
```

and then create product. It will be start from **1**

Comment: It might be useful to also remove the url_keys: `DELETE FROM url_rewrite WHERE entity_type='product';` (see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191656/magento-2-how-can-i-remove-all-products-url-rewrites). Url keys are not deleted by the code above.

Comment: There are a lot of catalog_product_* tables, so only deleting 1 or 2 of them is not a clean solution.

Comment: This would be a clean approach https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252209/delete-all-products

Comment: On a 500k catalog_product_entity table the delete part won't be fast. You might disable foreign keys check to make it a bit faster but you get orphan data instead.

Answer (score 6):

**Run Below SQL**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_compare_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_price_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_stock_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_eav_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_bundle_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_downlod_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_opt_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_price_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_index_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_relation`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_idx`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status_tmp`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_purchased_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_link_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `downloadable_sample_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `product_alert_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_compared_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `report_viewed_product_index`;
DELETE FROM url_rewrite where entity_type = 'product';
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) VALUES (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) VALUES (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
INSERT  INTO `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`website_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,0,'Default');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```